How can I write if/else function shorthand?
For example, I have a var a. I want to use one function if a is 1 if a is anything else I want to use another function without reusing a bunch of code. Here is something similar I have now:
if (a == 1) {
  return this.data.some((c) => {...});
} else {
  return this.data.every((c) => {...});
}

I have the same data in each elipsis that I do not want to repeat again. Is there a short way I can swap some for every depending on if (a == 1)?
I tried a regular ternary expression but the syntax isn't correct for functions, only variables.

You can define your anonymous function above, then use it in a ternary.
const myFunc = (c) => { ... };
return a == 0 ? this.data.some(myFunc) : this.data.every(myFunc);

Technically, there's nothing stopping you from making a ternary with two identical anonymous functions, perhaps you had another issue when you tried that? This should work:
return a == 0 ? this.data.some((c) => { ... }) : this.data.every((c) => { ... })


Defining the anonymous function then using it in a ternary worked, thanks!

You can do something like this:
const someOrEvery = a == 1 ? [].some : [].every;

return someOrEvery.call(this.data, (c) => {...});

With the call you can pass the argument (c) => {...} to some() or every() based on the ternary above.
